# Escaping hyphens with the mysql commandline tool

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to escape a hyphen with the mysql commandline tool?

I basically need to do this:

```
mysql  -hlocalhost -uuser -puser information_schema -e  "CREATE DATABASE foo-bar"
```

Using mysqladmin is not an option due to the framework I'm within.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"CREATE DATABASE \`foo-bar\`"

Comment: Make sure to remove the escaped backticks when running this commany yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Using backticks and using this way of piping the statement to mysql works:

```
echo 'create database `foo-bar2`' | mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

// John

Comment: You don't need to hijack my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes (" "), that would need no escaping.

```
create database "foo-bar"
```

---

Hope this helps.

Peace.